# How to check all checkboxes using JS?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, forms, checked

I want to check all checkboxes using javascript. When I click on submit button all the checkboxes should be checked. However all the checkboxes are checked just for a few seconds.

What am I doing wrong?

**html**:

```
<form method="post" name="myform">
  <input type="checkbox" name="h" value="1" id="g">Reading<br/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="h" value="2" id="g">php<br/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="h" value="3" id="g">playing<br/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="h" value="4" id="g">Gaming<br/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="h" value="5" id="g">Coding<br/>  
  <input type="submit" name="sub" value="submit" onclick="checkall(document.myform.h)" >
</form>
```

**javascript code**:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function checkall(chk){       
    for(var i = 0; i < chk.length; i++) {
     chk[i].checked = true;    
    }   
  }
  </script>
```

Comment: Is it necessary to use `<input type='submit'>`?

Comment: checked for a few second and than what happens ?

Comment: Most probably after submitting the form, you reload the page that causing the disappearing of checkbox tick.

Answer (score 3):

the problem is you are using a submit button within a form, which on click will submit the form.

So one solution is to change the button form a submit button to a normal button which will not trigger the submit of the form.

```js
function checkall(chk) {
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < chk.length; i++) {
    chk[i].checked = true;
    //return true;
  }

}
```

```html
<form method="post" name="myform">
  <input type="checkbox" name="h" value="1" id="g">Reading
  <br/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="h" value="2" id="g">php
  <br/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="h" value="3" id="g">playing
  <br/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="h" value="4" id="g">Gaming
  <br/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="h" value="5" id="g">Coding
  <br/>
  <!--<input type="radio" name="gen" value="male">Male<br/>-->
  <!--<input type="radio" name="gen" value="female">Female<br/>-->
  <input type="button" name="sub" value="submit" onclick="checkall(document.myform.h)">

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

your code is working just stop from form submit will solve your problem use `<form method="post" name="myform" onsubmit="return false">` and use ajax to get data.

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uzw7r64q/)**

Answer (score 0):

You created a form.And form will be submit after click on submit button.You can use following approach to select all checkbox only.

step 1- Write following statement in html.

```
      <input type="checkbox" name="h" value="1" class="g">Reading<br/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="h" value="2" class="g">php<br/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="h" value="3" class="g">playing<br/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="h" value="4" class="g">Gaming<br/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="h" value="5" class="g">Coding<br/>  
  <input type="button" name="sub" value="check all" id='custom_button'>
```

step 2- Write following statement in js file-

```
jQuery('#custom_button').click(function(){
     jQuery('.g').each(function() { //loop through each checkbox
                this.checked = true; //deselect all checkboxes with class "checkbox1"                       
            });      
});
```

Above statement will select all checkbox after click on button.

If you want to check example please use this link - http://jsfiddle.net/oxg3p1ny/1/